# Xcode storyboard ViewController display different

Tags: xcode

Why  the two ViewController have two kind?

How to do can make then the same?

In my case I have three type of the phone style on the same storyboard...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click the viewcontroller window and go to the right menu and then find the "Transition Style" select what you want